# One recipe for multiple targets with static pattern rules?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

what is the best way using make to achieve the following:

### input files

```
$PRJ/lib/foo.c
$PRJ/app/bar.c
$PRJ/app/baz.c
```

### output files shall be (using GCC):

```
$PRJ/obj/foo.o
$PRJ/obj/bar.o
$PRJ/obj/baz.o
```

Please notice that the input c-files are not in the same folders and I want to automate the collection of the input files.

This example here (using static pattern rules) only works if the c-files are all in the same folder but how is this gonna work for the above case?

```
SOURCES  = $(shell find $(PRJ)/app -type f -name *.c)
OBJECTS  = $(patsubst $(PRJ)/app/%, $(PRJ)/obj/%, $(SOURCES:.c=.o))

.PHONY: build
build: $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS): $(PRJ)/obj/%.o: $(PRJ)/app/%.c)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: There is no way to do this without writing multiple rules.  If you really have a lot of them you can use define/foreach/eval to generate them rather than writing them out by hand.  But if there are only two it's not worth the added complexity (IMO).  Also just an aside: remember that if you put all the outputs into the same directory you must be sure that none of your input filenames are the same (e.g., you can't have both `$PRJ/lib/foo.c` and `$PRJ/app/foo.c`)

Comment: @MadScientist It is doable with a single rule. You create a `.o` -> `.c` map (e.g. by [zipping](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/makefile/6154/advanced-makefile/23643/zipping-lists#t=201610191924516496058) over `$(eval somemagic_$1 := $2)`), then use secondary expansion to get the prerequisite (e.g. `$$(somemagic_$$@)`). Now, if doing that is worthwhile for two dirs is another story...

Comment: @AndreaBiondo I think using the define/eval method I suggested is simpler and more readable than that :)

Comment: @MadScientist Absolutely :) I just like to think of ways to abuse make. I'm embarassed I didn't think of vpath though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [the vpath directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search):

```
SOURCES := $(shell find $(PRJ) -type f -name "*.c")
# $(PRJ)/lib/foo.c $(PRJ)/app/bar.c $(PRJ)/app/baz.c

SOURCE_DIRS := $(sort $(dir $(SOURCES)))
# $(PRJ)/app/ $(PRJ)/lib/

OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.c,$(PRJ)/obj/%.o, $(notdir $(SOURCES)))
# $(PRJ)/obj/foo.o $(PRJ)/obj/bar.o $(PRJ)/obj/baz.o

.PHONY: build
build: $(OBJECTS)

vpath %.c $(SOURCE_DIRS)

$(OBJECTS): $(PRJ)/obj/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: This is very nice.

Comment: @MadScientist: If I thought of an elegant solution to a Make problem *you* thought was impossible, it can only mean that you're suffering from food poisoning.

Comment: Great! Thank's a million!